Inconsistent structure next to the corner seam
What could be the reason these defomations show on my 3D print?



I've tested it with different PLA filaments (different colors, different manufacturers), every time it's happening. I'm using Cura slicer and Anycubic Kobra 2 Max printer.
Tinkered with the print settings:

changed to random seam caused zits and blobs everywhere;
higher temperature caused stringing, lower temperature didn't help at all;
lowered inside wall printing speed from 160 to 80 mm/s (no difference);
increased retraction rate from 40 to 80 mm/s (no difference);
changed travel speed from 120 to 300 mm/s (no difference);
Z hop is off;
wall thickness = 0,8 mm;
layer height = 0,2 mm, nozzle = 0,4 mm;
infill: lighting, 10 %;
printing temperature = 210 °C, build plate = 60 °C

First layer is always perfect, 95 % of the print also looks well. It's just this 5 % that looks awful, especially at the inner seam inside.
What might be an issue? Is it a underextrusion or some settings in the slicer?

You don't have filament in time after a move. You should try to lower printing speed even further.

I will try doing it. What about retraction settings, maybe i should disable retraction between layers? Or incerase pressure?

How did you adjust your belts? If the belts have any slack at all, you'll get inconsistent prints. I'm talking about the two x-axis and one y-axis belts. The belt which goes around the top of the two z-axis screws doesn't really do much, so is inconsequential.

PS: I may have x and y axis backwards ... I can never remember, lol.
